# Scaling icon (<use>) to screen size independently of viewBox

Tags: svg

I'm creating a map-like display using an SVG image.
I've plotted a bunch of cities using their lat,lng coordinates, and I want to use the viewBox to zoom and pan on the map.
I want to use icons for these cities, and the `use` element seems ideal for this.

I'd like for the size of these icons to stay the same regardless of the size of the viewBox. Say, big cities should always have a width of 1cm on screen, smaller cities could be 0.8cm, etc.

I get the impression from the documentation that the units can be either px or for example cm or em. But is there a way to mix different coordinate systems to achieve what I want?
When I set the width and height of the `use` element to `1cm` or `1em`, they seem to become way too big.

My testing svg so far:

```html
<svg width="80vw" height="80vh" version="1.0" viewBox="4.34 -52.45 0.85 0.5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <svg version="1.0" viewBox="-1.2 -1.2 2.4 2.4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="icon">
      <!--<rect x="-1" y="-1" width="2" height="2" fill="red"/> -->
      <polygon points="0,1 0.866,-0.5 -0.866,-0.5" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="10%" stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-linejoin="round" color="deepskyblue" />
    </svg>
  </defs>
  <rect x="4.34" y="-52.45" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="0.001"/> <!-- show viewBox -->
  <g  transform="scale(1,-1)"> <!-- flip y coordinates so I can plot lat lng easily-->
    
    <!-- the circles indicate the positions I want the icons to have -->
    <circle r="0.020" cx="4.900000" cy="52.378333" />
    <circle r="0.016" cx="5.109900" cy="52.089300" />
    <circle r="0.010" cx="4.356165" cy="52.006627" />
    
    <use href="#icon" x="4.900000" y="52.378333" width="10%" height="10%" /> <!-- so far I've found using percentages comes closest to what I want, but I can't use them in a transform to center the icon -->
    <!-- <use href="#icon" x="4.900000" y="52.378333" width="1cm" height="1cm" /> WAY too big -->
    <use href="#icon" x="5.109900" y="52.089300" width="0.032" height="0.032" />
    <use href="#icon" x="4.356165" y="52.006627" width="0.020" height="0.020" transform="translate(-0.01 -0.01)" />
    
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: If you want things to stay the same size, don't use a viewBox at all.